# How to change text of specific option in select on/off switch?

Tags: jquery, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change slider switch text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231998/how-to-change-slider-switch-text)

I have in HTML this simple jQuery with standard selects switch.
And I want to change text of specific option after page is loaded (ready). Value is changed but it is not updated in the browser. It seems impossible to do without some tweak or workaround.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
              <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#set_slider option[value='0']").text('before') ;
    $("#set_slider").change();

function clickz(){
       $("#set_slider option[value='0']").text('after') ;
        $("#set_slider").change();
    $("#set_slider").selectmenu('refresh', true);
        $("#txt").html($("#set_slider option[value='0']").text());
    }
</script>
             <select name="set_slider" id="set_slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="false" >
                    <option value="0" >SET</option>
                    <option value="1" >OFF</option>
      </select>
      <div id=txt></div>
<input type='button' onclick='clickz();' value='Update'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233065/93966

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
$("#set_slider").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

As the list line of `clickz`.

Comment: I've tryed it unfortunately no help/changes calling $("#set_slider").selectmenu('refresh', true); at least in IE and FF.